# label angle in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, angle, tikz-angles

I'm trying to label the angle between the horizontal side and the oblique side but I do not know how to do this since I'm just a beginner in tikz. Could someone help me with this. The following is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (6,3);

    \draw[thick] (P)--(Q)--(R)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the missing lines of code next time, which allows compilation of your code snippet. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, and to help you in your future researches, you could benefit from the search engine here. [You could have found this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691387/tikz-label-angle-between-vectors?rq=1), for example, which does what you asked for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

- `angles`-library marks angles as given
- `quotes` is needed to insert text `" .. "` which includes math mode `$ .. $` which can render e.g. greek letters
- note: `{angle=P--Q--R}` marks the outer angle

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}% see ch. 41 in the pgfmanual


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (6,3);

    \draw[thick] (P)--(Q)--(R)--cycle;
    
    \pic[draw,->]   {angle=R--Q--P};
    \pic[draw,angle radius=1.5cm,<->,"$\psi$"] 
                    {angle=Q--P--R};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without the use of the library?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way without using the angles library. The basic idea is simple:

- move the pen (so to say) to the starting position `\draw (1,0)`
- draw an arc from there `arc(0:30:1);` (startAngle:stopAngle:radius)

Downsides:

- now you have to know or calculate the required angle yourself
- here I did it manually: 26.6 deg
- you need to put the text-label yourself
- using polar coordinates is useful here `(13.3:1.5)` , i.e. at 13.3 deg and radius 1.5

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (Q) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (R) at (6,3);

    \draw[thick] (P)--(Q)--(R)--cycle;
    
    \draw (1,0) arc(0:26.6:1);
    \node at (13.3:1.5) {$\beta$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```